# UIView отрисовывается за пределами родительской UIView

Tags: objective-c, uiview

Доброго времени суток! Вопрос по Objective-c. Имеется два UIVIew. Первый находится на самом контроллере, а второй находится на первом UIView. Если я изменю координаты второго на отрицательные, то он начинает отрисовываться за пределами родительского (первого). Как От этого избавиться?
P.S.:Используется для параллакс эффекта при прокрутке текста. Задний фон уезжает за край, и начинает отрисовываться поверх статус бара.

Answer (score 1):

Я так понимаю, вы хотите чтоб родитель обрезал дочерний вью и не давал ему отрисовываться за своими пределами. Если так, вам надо на родительском вью поставить `parentView.clipsToBounds = YES;`